# Populate indexed table in Oracle using Informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm new to both Oracle and Informatica.
Currently working on a small task where I need to select all records from the source table, filter the results to get only records where field1='Y' and finally insert new rows into the target table that contains only src.field2 and src.field3 values.

These 2 fields are used for the PK and for the Index of the target table.

So i get an error  in Informatica:

> "ORA-26002: Table has index defined upon it"

I rather not dropping the index? is there a work around?

I've tried alter index to "unusable" but I got the same error.

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://informaticadeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/ora-26002-table-has-index-defined-upon-it/) what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Normal` load mode instead of `Bulk`. You can set in session properties for the target.